# Expected number of spaces that have atleast 1 resident out of total n rooms and m residents.

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have n rooms and m possible residents. I can assign people uniformly randomly to each room, i.e each person is independently assigned. I have to find the expected number of rooms with at least 1 person.

My effort till now:

1. Since there are 'n' rooms and 'm' possible residents, the "expected" number of people on each room should simply be $\frac{m}{n}$. I believe this will be used somewhere but I am unsure.
2. Moving away from point 1:
   The probability of 1 room having at least 1 resident should be $\frac{1}{m}$. Summing this probability for all rooms should give us the expected fraction of rooms that will have at least 1 resident. Since there are many ways to select a resident, we will have $m \choose n$ options, thus giving us :
   E[number of rooms with at least 1 resident] = $\frac{m \choose n}{n}$ = $\frac{(m-1)!}{(m-n)!n!}$

***I may be wildly off, but I believe I have a grasp of what I have to do, but not exactly sure if I am pursuing the right direction.***

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the way the question is worded, I assume that any number of residents from $0$ to $m$ inclusive can be assigned to a single room.  Thus, what is the probability that any given room will remain unoccupied?  This is $$\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^m.$$  This is because each resident has a probability of $1 - 1/n$ of not being assigned to that room, and there are $m$ residents who are independently assigned.

Since there are $n$ rooms, this means the expected number of empty rooms is simply $n$ times the above probability, due to linearity of expectation.  So the expected number of rooms with at least one resident assigned will be $$n\left(1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^m \right).$$

This calculation does not apply if there is a limit to the number of residents that can be assigned to a single room; e.g., if $m > 2$ and there can be at most $2$ residents assigned to a room.

Comment: I understood you method but don't quite get how linearity of expectation comes into play here?

Comment: @10Minhelp Linearity of expectation states that for random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$, not necessarily independent, $$\operatorname{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}[X_i].$$  If we define $$X_i = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{room } i \text{ has at least one resident} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ that is to say $X_i$ is an indicator random variable that is $1$ if and only if room $i$ is assigned, then the total number of occupied rooms is $\sum X_i$.  Then $\operatorname{E}[X_i] = \Pr[X_i = 1]$ and the result follows.